# Calculating the Number of Orders Required Based on A Given ROI

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a marketer trying to figure out the amount of orders or revenue required to get an ROI of 25% from digital advertising.

To calculate a more accurate ROI, I'm incorporating COGS with the formula: `ROI = (GR - (AS + O * COGS))/(AS + O * COGS)`

GR = Gross Revenue
AS = Advertising Budget
O = Orders
COGS = Cost of Goods Sold

The Known Values Are:

`COGS:   $28`
`Advertising Spend: $25000.`

However, I still have 2 unknowns (Gross Revenue and Orders). Is it possible to still figure out either Orders or Gross Revenue?

`

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @saulspatz is it possible to figure out Revenue or Orders?

Comment: How would I know?  All you've given us is a formula with no context at all.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry, I'm new to this. What context am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an equation linking orders to gross revenue.  If you always sell at the same price gross revenue is just the product of the price and the number of orders.  If not, you need to figure some sort of average selling price and multiply the number of orders by that to get gross revenue.  Then you will have only one variable and can solve for it.

Added you have $$0.25=\frac {45\cdot O - AS - 28 \cdot O}{AS + 28 \cdot O}\\AS+28\cdot O=4(17\cdot O-AS)\\5\cdot AS=40\cdot O\\O=\frac {25000}8=3125$$

Comment: I have an average order value at `$45`. However, I can't figure out anything without knowing the amount of orders. I could substitute orders to refer to revenue i.e. r/45 or I could revenue to refer to orders as O*45. However, I still don't know where to go from there.

Comment: I don't follow that equation. can you please explain to me the different stages

Comment: If I follow you correctly. If I wanted to create a formula that finds O each time. it would be O = (ROI * A) + A / AOV - COGS - (ROI*COGS). WHERE AOV is average order value

Comment: I get $O=\frac {A\cdot ROI+A}{AOV-COGS+ROI\cdot COGS}$.  I think your parentheses are not right, but you have the idea.

Comment: great, this is exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly